# How to fill form on other website, click on button and after reload get information from answer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-chrome-devtools, google-rich-snippets

There iput on website:

```
<input type="text"  name="url" value="example.com">
```

I need to will in with data from my array, then press button

```
<input type="submit" name="proceed" value="го!" >
```

When webpage is reloaded I need to get **NUMBER** from `<b>` with style `color:red`:

```
<td>
  ....
  <br>
  Result: <b>some numbers</b> / more numbers = <b style="color:red">NUMBER</b> <br>
  ....
</td>
```

How to get final array with "website-NUMBER" info?

No I have such code:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
//this code loades jQuery

setTimeout(function () {
    var arr = [ "ya.ru", "google.com", "ok.ru", "vk.com", "fb.com" ];  // example list of websites I need to put in input    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $('input[name=url]').val(arr[i]); //put website in form
        $('input[name=proceed]').click(); //click on button
    }
        alert(arr);    
}, 1000); // timeout to give jquery time to be loaded
```

I have number of questions:

1. My code reloads page only when it pastes all data from array, I need
   to reload it (click on button) after every past of data from array
2. I found code which finds element by style, but I don't understand
   how to save it in new array with current input value.

   $('b').filter(function() {
       return $(this).css('color') == 'red';
   })
3. How to add new value to new array with website (current unput value)
   and NUMBER

My code works in Google Chrome snippet.

Comment: You can use phantom.js or casper.js

Comment: `timeout to give jquery time to be loaded` - that will never fail, until it does

Comment: @binariedMe I don't know them. How phantom.js or casper.js will help?

Comment: @JaromandaX so on what it has influence?

Comment: instead of setTimeout(fn ...) do jq.addEventListener('load', fn ...) ... now your code that requires jQuery will not run until jQuery is loaded ... pretty sure chrome will fire that load event - it's a bit hit and miss with chrome, but that's mainly iframe onload events ... alternatively, **don't use jquery for such a simple task**

Comment: @JaromandaX do you have any ideas how to find element by style withour jquery (see part question 2 below)?

Comment: @JaromandaX I rewrote this code